# Display coverage report on browser

Tags: javascript, jestjs, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

When you run tests in a GitHub Actions workflow, a coverage report will be generated. Now every time i run a test and a new coverage report is generated, I want to store the coverage folder in mongodb, and view the report of each generated coverage by opening the index.html on the browser, which is in Icov-report folder. To be able to view different reports, I will be using unique id like time stamp or run_id.

How do i do it? If there is any other better approach, please do suggest.

For now, this is my approach to store coverage in mongodb:-

store-coverage.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const core = require('@actions/core');
const {DefaultArtifactClient} = require('@actions/artifact');
const artifact = new DefaultArtifactClient();

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const uniqueId = new Date().toISOString;

async function storeCoverageReport() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db('coverage-reports');
    const collection = db.collection('reports');

    const rootDirectory = 'coverage'; // Path to the coverage folder
    const {id, size} = await artifact.uploadArtifact('coverage-report', {rootDirectory});
    
    console.log(`upload id and size: ${id}, ${size}`);
    const coverageReportBuffer = await compressCoverageFolder(rootDirectory);

    const result = await collection.insertOne({
      _id: uniqueId,
      coverageReport: coverageReportBuffer,
    });

    console.log(`Coverage report stored with ID: ${result.insertedId}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error storing coverage report:', err);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

async function compressCoverageFolder(rootDirectory) {
    const coverageReportArchive = archiver('zip');
    const coverageReportBuffer = [];
  
    coverageReportArchive.on('data', (chunk) => {
      coverageReportBuffer.push(chunk);
    });
  
    coverageReportArchive.on('end', () => {
      return Buffer.concat(coverageReportBuffer);
    });
  
    coverageReportArchive.directory(rootDirectory, false);
    await coverageReportArchive.finalize();
  
    return coverageReportArchive.pointer();
  }

storeCoverageReport();
```

CD workflow

```
name: CD Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging

env:
   EC2_HOST: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && secrets.EC2_HOST ||  secrets.STAGING_EC2_HOST }}
   EC2_USER: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && secrets.EC2_USER ||  secrets.STAGING_EC2_USER }}
   EC2_KEY: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY ||  secrets.STAGING_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
   ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.USER_PAT }}

jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: self-hosted
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
               
            - name: Set up Node
              uses: actions/setup-node@v4
              with:
                node-version: 18
               
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: npm ci

            - name: Run tests
              run: npm run test -- --json --outputFile=test-results.json
              continue-on-error: true # Continue even if tests fail to calculate coverage

            - name: Calculate test pass rate
              id: test_pass_rate
              run: |
               node -e 'const fs = require("fs");
               const testResults = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("test-results.json", "utf8"));
               const totalTests = testResults.numTotalTests;
               const passedTests = testResults.numPassedTests;
               const passRate = (passedTests / totalTests) * 100;
               console.log(`Test Pass Rate: ${passRate.toFixed(2)}%`);
               console.log(`::set-output name=pass_rate::${passRate.toFixed(2)}`);'

            - name: Check pass rate
              run: |
                 if (( $(echo "${{ steps.test_pass_rate.outputs.pass_rate }}" | cut -d'.' -f1) < 90 )); then
                   echo "Test pass rate is less than 90% in main branch."
                   exit 1
                 fi

            - name: Archive coverage report
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
              with:
                name: coverage-report
                path: coverage/
                if-no-files-found: warn

            - name: Install MongoDB dependencies
              run: npm install mongodb

            - name: Store coverage report in MongoDB
              env:
                MONGODB_URI: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_URI }}
              run: |
                node .github/workflows/store-coverage.js  
            
            - name: Login to Docker
              uses: docker/login-action@v2
              with:
                username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
                password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}

            - name: Pull latest code into EC2, push latest code to container and Restart Server
              if: steps.test_pass_rate.outputs.pass_rate >= 90
              run: |
                echo "$EC2_KEY" > ec2_key.pem
                chmod 600 ec2_key.pem
                ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ec2_key.pem $EC2_USER@$EC2_HOST <<EOF
                # sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
                # newgrp docker
                # docker tag ondc-sellerapp-server omgvaibhav/ondc-sellerapp-server
                # docker push omgvaibhav/ondc-sellerapp-server:latest
                cd ~/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp
                git pull
                npm ci
                # use pm2 reload server for zero-downtime
                pm2 restart server
                EOF
```

Error:

```
Run node .github/workflows/store-coverage.js  
Artifact name is valid!
Error storing coverage report: Error: The provided rootDirectory undefined does not exist
    at validateRootDirectory (/home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/upload/upload-zip-specification.js:37:15)
    at /home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/upload/upload-artifact.js:49:62
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/upload/upload-artifact.js:31:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/upload/upload-artifact.js:27:12)
    at uploadArtifact (/home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/upload/upload-artifact.js:47:12)
    at DefaultArtifactClient.<anonymous> (/home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/client.js:42:61)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/***/actions-runner/_work/ONDC-SellerApp/ONDC-SellerApp/node_modules/@actions/artifact/lib/internal/client.js:8:71
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, It seems that there is a wrong argument passed to the validateRootDirectory() function.

From what I could find by a quick look at the source:

When using [`uploadArtifact(artifactName, filesToUpload, rootDirectory, options)`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/blob/ef09cdac3e2d3e60d8ccadda691f4f1cec5035cb/src/upload/upload-artifact.ts#L70C3-L75C6), the 3rd argument has to be the rootDirectory as a native string.

So

```js
const {id, size} = await artifact.uploadArtifact('coverage-report', {rootDirectory});
```

seems to be the cause of your issue.